# How would I retrieve the username of a channel when only having the display name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, youtube-api

I am using the `Youtube v3.0 Data API`, the REST API, even though I am using Node.js.

I only have the Display Name of a YouTube Channel(such as `Traversy Media`, or `Android Developers`) and I need to get the ID of the channel from only their name.

Right now I am using their Display Name and just hoping that it is also their Username. I am getting their ID from that. But most channels Display Names aren't the same as their Usernames.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=${config.key}&forUsername=${name}&part=id
```

That is how I am currently retrieving the ID, but like I said, the Username isn't always the Display Name.

So again, how would I get the ID from the Display Name?

Comment: Well can't multiple users have the same display name? If thats the case, youre going to have to query and get multiple users back, and select the one you need.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine My goal is to not use display names. My project will be impossible if I have to rely on Display Names. I need to get the **usernames**

Comment: Yeah I get that, but what I'm saying is that if multiple users can have the **same** display name, the only way to get a **username** from a **display name** is to query for users based on a display name, and then select the user you want.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine OHH My bad. You are right. I will just do the first result and it will have the highest amount of subscribers so that should work out. But yeah you are right, I will be weary of this. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you must use the Search part of the api, like this call for example 
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={KEY}&part=snippet&type=channel&maxResults=1&q=traversy+media`

You would obviously replace KEY with your API key generated from the google cloud console.

That call above returns,

```js
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/TA3dq6AD2oajHPE0-0Y9hZzSmi8\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
 "regionCode": "US",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 34,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/SJmA2ZkjStP6_YHYQcEsg9JrWz4\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#channel",
    "channelId": "UC29ju8bIPH5as8OGnQzwJyA"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2009-10-30T21:33:14.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC29ju8bIPH5as8OGnQzwJyA",
    "title": "Traversy Media",
    "description": "Traversy Media features the best online web development and programming tutorials for all of the latest web technologies including Node.js, Angular 2, React.js, ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-OsgBxXITFdg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/gDaUV_aSb2Q/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-OsgBxXITFdg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/gDaUV_aSb2Q/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-OsgBxXITFdg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/gDaUV_aSb2Q/s800-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Traversy Media",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "upcoming"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

(ignore the snippet part, just using it to show the response)